# How to Query this in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am having 3 tables has shown below

```
tbMaster
Branch_code Sale_No Amount  Type_Code
-------------------------------------
0           1222    421.00  9
0           1227    323.00  9
0           1228    1186.00 9
0           1223    119.00  2
```

and

```
tType 
Type_Code   Type_Name
1              NTB
2              TABLE SERVICE
3              A/C TABLE  SERVICE
4              TAKE AWAY
5              CAR SERVICE
6              HOME DELIVERY
7              SELF SERVICE
```

and finally

```
tFree
Type_Code   Branch_code    Amount
-----------------------------------
1           0               261.00
1           0               112.20
1           0               336.60
```

Now i am getting the output as say for example

```
Branch_code  TypeTcount SaleValue   Type_Name
NULL            0        0.00          NTB
0               1        910.00        TABLE SERVICE
NULL            0        0.00          A/C TABLE  SERVICE
NULL            0        0.00          TAKE AWAY
NULL            0        0.00          CAR SERVICE
NULL            0        0.00          HOME DELIVERY
NULL            0        0.00          SELF SERVICE
```

Now my query is

```
SELECT
    sm.Branch_code,
    COUNT(sm.Sale_No) TypeTcount,
    ISNULL(SUM(sm.Amount), 0) SaleValue,
    t.Type_Name
FROM [tMaster] sm
RIGHT JOIN [tType] t
    ON sm.Type_Code = t.Type_Code
    AND sm.Branch_code = 0
GROUP BY
    t.Type_Name,
    t.Type_Code
ORDER BY t.Type_Code
```

But I want to get the count of `Type_code` from the table `tFree` in the output `TypeTCount`.

Expected Result:

```
  Branch_code    TypeTcount SaleValue   Type_Name
    NULL            3        709.80        NTB
    0               1        910.00        TABLE SERVICE
    NULL            0        0.00          A/C TABLE  SERVICE
    NULL            0        0.00          TAKE AWAY
    NULL            0        0.00          CAR SERVICE
    NULL            0        0.00          HOME DELIVERY
    NULL            0        0.00          SELF SERVICE
```

Just show the `tFree` table records near `NTB`

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Without affecting the rest of your query, you might try a [correlated subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638) to get this count:

```
SELECT
    sm.Branch_code,
    -- Correlated subquery to count rows:
    (select count(*) from tFree where Type_Code = t.Type_Code) TypeTcount,
    ISNULL(SUM(sm.Amount), 0) SaleValue,
    t.Type_Name
FROM [tMaster] sm
RIGHT JOIN [tType] t
    ON sm.Type_Code = t.Type_Code
    AND sm.Branch_code = 0
GROUP BY
    t.Type_Name,
    t.Type_Code
ORDER BY t.Type_Code
```

Note that this can often incur a performance penalty compared to a join, however, as it will probably run the count as a nested loop. Here is one possiblity to do this as a join:

```
SELECT
    sm.Branch_code,
    COUNT(t.Type_Code) TypeTcount,
    ISNULL(SUM(sm.Amount), 0) SaleValue,
    t.Type_Name
FROM [tMaster] sm
RIGHT JOIN [tType] t
    ON sm.Type_Code = t.Type_Code
    AND sm.Branch_code = 0
-- Join table to count rows:
LEFT JOIN [tFree] f
    ON t.Type_Code = f.Type_Code
GROUP BY
    t.Type_Name,
    t.Type_Code
ORDER BY t.Type_Code
```

Last thing to mention is that I didn't correct anything to do with Branch_Code or your example query beyond the count in question. I don't fully trust your sample data yet so I left the rest of your query alone, although it looks like it would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    sm.Branch_code,
    COUNT(sm.Sale_No) TypeTcount,
    ISNULL(SUM(sm.Amount), 0) SaleValue,
    t.Type_Name,
    (SELECT Count(Type_code) FROM tFree  WHERE tFree.Type_Code = t.Type_Code AND tFree.Branch_code = sm.Branch_code) AS Count_of_Type_code
FROM [tMaster] sm
RIGHT JOIN [tType] t
    ON sm.Type_Code = t.Type_Code
    AND sm.Branch_code = 0
GROUP BY
    sm.Branch_code
    t.Type_Name,
    t.Type_Code
ORDER BY t.Type_Code
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the sample data if Branch_Code could or should be used here.